# Clients in Dask DataFrame with python | client.shutdown()

Tags: python, dataframe, client, dask

I have been working with **dask** and I have a question related the **clients** when you are processing a large script with high computational requirements

```
client = Client(n_workers = NUM_PARALLEL)
...
more code
...
client.shutdown()
```

I have seen some people that are **shutting down the client in the middle** of the process and then and then initializing it again, is it good for speed?

On the other hand, the workers are running out of memory, do you know if its a good practise to **compute()  several times the dask dataframe** instead of computing it only once at the end, that may be beyond the performance capacity of the pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have seen some people that are shutting down the client in the middle of the process and then and then initializing it again, is it good for speed?

IIUC, there is no effect on speed, there might be slight slow down in terms of time to spin up a scheduler/cluster. The only slight advantage is if you are sharing resources, then shutting down the cluster will free up the resources.

> On the other hand, the workers are running out of memory, do you know if its a good practise to compute() several times the dask dataframe instead of computing it only once at the end, that may be beyond the performance capacity of the pc.

This really depends on the DAG, there might be an advantage in computing at an intermediate step if it reduces the number of partitions/tasks, especially if some of the results are computed multiple times.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I see those things are not making any big change, good to know. The workers are exceeding 95% memory budget, for letting them work I should reduce the number of them to give them more ram to each one. I will try reducing  until it works. Thanks again!